# Remove Controls in MediaElement player. Where to add/change the code

Tags: javascript, templates, mediaelement.js

This is a very basic question about where to change or add code. 
I want to remove some of the controls on a media element player. 
There is information everywhere on the internet which in summary states.

You can control what buttons appear on the control bar by setting the `{features:['playpause','backlight']}` array etc...

My question is where do I go to change or insert the code `{features:` etc...

I see the folders media `front/players/osmplayer/player/templates` etc. 
And there are several src query-ui js folders and files.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. If you have ever changed the features of your player can I ask what folder and file did you go to to insert or alter the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the features you want/need in your own custom MEJS initialization script like :

```
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer({
   features:['playpause','progress','volume'],
   alwaysShowControls: false
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XBd7S/)**